# VS2019 Nsight extension installed, not showing up in Manage Extension and impossible to disable

Tags: visual-studio, nsight

I have the Nsight extension installed on VS2019 and it shows up in the menu:

[image]

Unfortunately, it makes Intellisense unbearably slow, so I would like to disable that extension, however, it doesn't show up in the Manage Extension Window:

[image]

The [Nsight doc](https://docs.nvidia.com/nsight-vs-integration/manage-tools/index.html#:%7E:text=To%20remove%20the%20Visual%20Studio,remove%20or%20disable%2Fenable%20it.) says it has to be disabled from the manage extension window:
[image]

How this issue can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled Nsight Integrate from the control panel and the problem was solved.